# display content from custom post type by month

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom post type called "**events**".

I wanted to make a list of months from a year that is clickable and then when click it will display all the post content from that month.

So whenever I click on a month for example I clicked on "january" of 2017.

It will show all posts from that month under it. example below

[image]

I have here a code which lists the months but links are not working

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$limit = 0;
$year_prev = null;
$months = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH( post_date ) AS month , YEAR( post_date ) AS year, COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( ) and post_type = 'events' GROUP BY month , year ORDER BY post_date ASC");
foreach($months as $month) :
    $year_current = $month->year;
    if ($year_current != $year_prev){
        if ($year_prev != null){?>

        <?php } ?>

    <div class="archive-year"><strong><?php echo $month->year; ?></strong></div>

    <?php } ?>
    <div><a href="#"><span class="archive-month"><?php echo date_i18n("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?></span></a></div>
<?php $year_prev = $year_current;

if(++$limit >= 18) { break; }

endforeach; ?>
```

sorry but I do not know how this works, thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of error do you face off? Anyway, as I understand, you want to list all post by given month, right? But in your query, I found that `and post_date <= now( )` and as you can see, `now()` is not a month...

Comment: there are no error, i just want to click on the month and all post under that month will display under, sorry, I just copied that code just to list the months, I don't know much about PHP

Answer (score 0):

I have made this function. in my function.php file

```
function post_type_Custom($where,$args){  
    $post_type  = isset($args['post_type'])  ? $args['post_type']  : 'post';  
    $where = "WHERE post_type = '$post_type' AND post_status = 'publish'";
    return $where;  
}
add_filter( 'getarchives_where','post_type_Custom',10,2);
```

now add following code wherever you want to display list by monthly

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'custom_post_type',
    'type'         => 'monthly',
    'echo'         => 0
);
echo '<ul>'.wp_get_archives($args).'</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

You Can do it using WordPress [date_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => 2017,
            'month' => 1
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$events = $query->posts;
foreach ($events as $event) {
    $event->ID:$event->post_title.<br>;
}
```